# Faker json data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Trying to create a json file that shows random fake data, I know how  to create fake data using faker npm. I installed json schema faker in the terminal.

This is the code I have tried but it brings up an error

```html
{
  "contact": {
    "type": "string",
    "name": "name.findName"
  }
}
```

I get an error with the :, any idea why this is?

Comment: The code snippet provided does nothing when run... Please provide the full command you're using, as well as the full error. That's valid JSON you have.

Comment: that is the code that I'm using

Comment: I'm completely lost

Comment: You seem to be mixing up array notation with object notation. Objects have properties and are surrounded with `{ }`. Ex: `{ "a": 1 }`. Arrays do not have properties and are surrounded with `[ ]`. Ex: `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

Comment: You should consider using a utility to validate your JSON file like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid JSON structure. Replace "[" with "{" E.g.

```
{
  "contact": {
    "type": "string",
    "name": "name.findName"
  }
}
```

Comment: I now get this error module.js:590
    throw err;
    ^

Comment: You must provide more info if I should be able to help you. Like a link to the npm package you are using, the code you are using, etc.

However, I think this: http://json-schema-faker.js.org/#gist/643581211616571b26bad3fe895a2ae8 is what you are aiming at.

Comment: reinstall npm and that fixed the problem